James Bond Inflatable Tent
I have vague memory from childhood of James Bond using an inflatable tent.
Something about - James and a lady being stuck in the countryside. James pulls out a package out of his car, which inflates into a tent.
Inside of the tent is luxurious, with inflatable bed, tables and lamps etc.
I've looked up lists of James Bond gadgets, but I can't see it mentioned.
Not sure which film it was, but I think it was an early one.
Is my memory faulty?  I've asked around but no one remembers it. :-)

The only inflatable thing I can remember is the "avalanche protection ball" in The World Is Not Enough. It's inflatable and James "gets stuck" in it with a girl, but the scene doesn't match the rest of the description. Maybe you've combined it with another scene, thinking it's part of the same? See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKqdgvsbfFQ

The only inflatable tent that comes to mind is in the movie "Moontrap" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911/). Walter Koenig and his lady companion inflate the tent on the surface of the moon and they have sex inside the tent. Obviously, this film is not a James Bond movie. At the top of the site below there is a picture of that Moontrap tent:
http://orbitalvector.com/Space%20Equipment/Pressure%20Tents/PRESSURE%20TENTS.htm

You are probably looking for the 1967 movie "The Ambushers", which is a parody of James Bond movies, starring Dean Martin.  From a commenter on IMDB:

Check out how Dino's car trunk pops out an inflatable tent complete with bed, nightstand, lamp and metal chairs!

Here's the link to the IMDB page, and here's the link to the page with that quote.
